# what is the best, efficient and professional way insert record in database laravel 5.2

Tags: mysql, laravel

I developing the on-line shopping system I have some table to make crude base
I want to insert record in professional and efficient way but I don't know what is the best way I'm use `here I mention two table product or company`

```
product fields     id p_name ,p_price,p_detail
company fields     id comp_name comp_detail
```

my controller like this

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Http\Requests; 
class Cdesigination extends Controller
{

    public function index()
    {
         $insertData = array(
        "name"      =>  Input::get("name"),
        "detail"    =>  Input::get("detail"),
        "token_key" =>  Input::get("_token")
    ); 
    return view('company');
    }

    public function product()
    {
         $record = array(
        "p_name"      =>  Input::get("name"),
        "p_price" =>  Input::get("price"),
        "p_detail"  =>  Input::get("detail")
    ); 

    return view('product');
    }

}
```

How to insert record in database what is the professional way in Laravel 5.2

Comment: If you're using laravel it would make sense to leverage eloquent, take a look at the `create` method

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent#basic-inserts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like to use `insert()` with [Mass Assignment](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent#mass-assignment) feature (don't forget to fill `$fillable` array for each model):

```
class Cdesigination extends Controller
{

    public function company(Request $request)
    {
        Company::insert($request->all());

        return view('company');
    }

    public function product(Request $request)
    {
        Product::insert($request->all());

        return view('product');
    }

}
```

It's short, readable and maintainable.

Comment: how to access $fillable array in controller for ex my model namespace App\models; 
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Designation extends Model
{  

   
} how to specifies table in model or controller where table is work on this method of controller please  explain it clear

Comment: You don't need to access it. You just need to add into your model and fill it once. After that mass assignment will work in every controller which will work with this model. You can read more about `$fillable`array by clicking the link in my answer.